# How to calculate linear index of fuzziness of an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fuzzy-logic

i am trying to calculate linear index of fuzziness of an image using this formula:
[image: Linear index of fuzziness formula]

i have to see a positive `y` value according to the paper. But i see a negative value, so i think i am doing something wrong. here is my try. and my [output_image](https://gofile.io/?c=KFIVDj)

```
q=(pi/2)*(1-output_image/255); %I is output image and 255 is maximum gray level. output_iamge is 288*384 double and grayscale image
y= sum(sum(min(q,1-q)))/(width*height); %M*N is width*height
```

Comment: The paper is probably wrong. I don’t even see how that equation could yield a measure of fuzziness. You might want to go back to the paper referenced.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a book and i can't reach it. Is my coding true, then?

Comment: Yes. If you remove the pi/2 from (11) you would get a measure between 0 and 1. Or use pi/2-q instead of 1-q, then you get a measure between 0 and pi/2.

Comment: The snapshot in the question seems to be  of the text from the pg#4 of this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8284291